# Windows 8 Stylesheet for QT5.4

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-designer

I want to give my QT5.4.1 app a modern look.

Since I am new to QT, I searched on google but I could not find a stylesheet that I liked (most of stylesheets are dark themed). As a matter of fact, I found very few examples.

Where can I find some stylesheets that look clean and light, for example, like windows 8 theme?

Comment: obs: i am a newbie using qt

Comment: Not a lot of people are posting their style sheets in the open. A year ago looking for open source qss, I didn't find anything usable, and certainly nothing like what I wanted. If you want 'windows 8', your best bet is implementing your own style class, or at least your own stye sheet.

Comment: This is very broad question. "Nice and clean" stylesheet is very subjective term.